# Is it possible to add or somehow relate a checkfiled to taxonomies?

Tags: 8, commerce, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to make something with the commerce module and I need to create options for my product and I was thinking making this via a taxonomy, but the options must be clickable (checkboxes) so ... is it possible to change taxonomies to checkboxes? if so, then how?

Comment: This is no problem, for a taxonomy field you can change the autocomplete to checkboxes in the form display.

Comment: but how is it done exactly? is there a tutorial online?

Comment: this should be in the same place where you add the taxonomy field to the the product type, look for a tab at the top of the page "Manage form display"

Comment: There is no way to change the addons into checkbox filed here http://i.imgur.com/IyRi2jC.png

Comment: You have to change the taxonomy field in the product type, not the taxonomy itself, see the screenshot in the answer

Answer (score 1):

To change the tag selection for a taxonomy field from autocomplete to check boxes go to the content type or product type and change the widget in the tab *Manage form display*:

[image]